# How to display database results as a reference to the actual data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a database that uses codes for data in some fields. So on insert I use a drop down list for input such as:

```
<option value="BAL">Bald</option>
<option value="BLK">Black</option>
<option value="BLN">Blond or Strawberry</option>
<option value="BRO">Brown</option>
<option value="GRY">Gray or Partially Gray</option>
```

For example.  However some of the field have hundreds of options.  When I query the database I would like to show the full text, not the code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create another table which stores complete names for these codes with respect to each code like as follow

```
Table2
__________________________________
|code     |name_to_display       |
__________________________________
|BAL      |Bald                  |
|BLK      |Black                 |
|BLN      |Blond or Strawberry   |
|BRO      |Brown                 |
|GRY      |Gray or Partially Gray|    
__________________________________
```

let us name it table2 where as the original table is named as table1. Now write a query like Select table1.*,table2.name_to_display from Table1 Left join table2 on table1.code = table2.code and instead of displaying the code you can display the data from name_to_display